# Prepared statement expects 0 params with 1 given .., using php manual example

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I took this straight from php manual example -- it was almost identical to what I needed but I am still getting this error.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT obitBody, Photo FROM tnObit WHERE obitID = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['obitID']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
```

> mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: It looks like you are mixing up PDO and MySQLi here... Your error is a `mysqli_stmt` error, but your syntax is that of PDO.  `$link` must be a `mysqli` object.  You need to use [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and `bind_result()`...

Comment: It doesn't look straight from php manual example to me.

Comment: You've read the entire manual? WOW!  

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['name']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: paxdiablo is correct, but @MichaelBerkowski is the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute` (the object-based one, as opposed to the older less-favored variant) doesn't actually *take* any parameters.

From your query and attempted parameters to `execute`, it looks like you're trying to pass the needed parameters as an array to the `execute` call. This is not how it's done.

You need to bind variables to the `?` markers in a separate call *before* calling `execute`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592975/mysqli-prepared-statement-proceeds-no-output) (once fixed with the accepted answer) shows the general process you need to follow:

- create statement;
- prepare statement;
- bind parameters;
- execute (with *no* parameters);
- store result (if buffering);
- bind result variables;
- fetch (in loop, most likely);
- close statement.